# Overriding jQuery Dialog method

Tags: jquery-ui

I am trying to override close method of Jquery Dialog method.

Code :

```
jQuery.Dialog.close = function() {
    alert('my close');
}
```

But its not working. Please help.

Comment: Basically i have multiple dialog box in a page. When close button is clicked i want to hide that dialog (not close). So i want to do dialog.hide() when close. So i want to override close method

Comment: When you say you want to hide it not close it, does that mean you want to retain the values? Until and unless you do not destroy the dialogue you will be able to retain it. in the close function inside the dialog , just say(#dialogname).hide(); and return false after that.

Answer (score 5):

There is an event called `beforeClose` which would allow you to do what you want, I think. When it fires, you can hide the dialog, then return false, which would prevent the dialog from actually closing.

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
   beforeClose: function(event, ui) { 
       $(this).hide();
       return false;
   }
});
```

Reference: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ under the Events tab below the example

Comment: beforeClose: "This event is triggered when a dialog attempts to close. If the beforeClose event handler (callback function) returns false, the close will be prevented."

Answer (score 3):

You're setting it up wrong. Check [this out](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#event-close) to see how to do it correctly.

Ok, so that link doesn't take you where I thought it would. Here's the relevant bit from jqueryui.com.

```
closeType:dialogclose
This event is triggered when the dialog is closed.

Code examples

Supply a callback function to handle the close event as an init option.
$('.selector').dialog({
   close: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
Bind to the close event by type: dialogclose.
$('.selector').bind('dialogclose', function(event, ui) {
  ...
});
```

Comment: I tried it but not working as i expected. My aim is when i hit the close button i want to hide() not to close.

Comment: i don't believe you can do this without modifying the actual jquery dialog code.